# How to get rid of strange tab in "emacs-mac" frame

Tags: osx, frames, emacs-mac-port

On macOS High Sierra I have install the  ["emacs-mac" Emacs port](https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac) via homebrew. The Emacs version now is 25.3.3.

When starting up Emacs I get this strange tab in my Emacs frame:

[image: Useless tab in Emacs frame]

I have set the Document tab setting "Prefer tabs when opening documents" in the Dock Preference pane to "Manually". I still have this useless tab.

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question has been posted and solved before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265615/emacs-mac-real-state/46274380).

More info on the issue can be found under [this Github ticket](https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport/issues/123#issuecomment-350513141).

So, to answer your question, you can do `M-x mac-toggle-tab-bar` and toggle with this the tab off.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @spav. However, as a detail `mac-toggle-tab-bar` is a function, not a variable. I have edited your answer accordingly. (The edit is now in the review queue.)